# How to do axios.get in react native?

Tags: react-native, axios

I am new to react native. I am trying to do axios.get(). But I am getting this in console:

```
        serverData: serverData
      })', '_this.setState' is undefined)]

_this.setState is not a function. (In '_this.setState({
    serverData: serverData
  })', '_this.setState' is undefined)
```

This my code:

```
export function FriendRequests ( ) {

state = {
    serverData: [],
};

axios.get('http://api.myslambook.in/swagger/#/users/', {
    auth: {
        username: 'xxxx',
        password: 'xxxxx'
    }
    }).then(res => {
        const serverData = res.data;
        this.setState({serverData});
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

return (
    <SearchableDropdown
        items={this.state.serverData}
        defaultIndex={1}
        resetValue={false}
        textInputProps={
                    {
                        placeholder: "placeholder",
                        underlineColorAndroid: "transparent",

                    }
                    }
                    listProps={
                    {
                        nestedScrollEnabled: true,
                    }
     }
    />

)
```

}
I have edited my code and provided more details. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: Sorry its not an error. Its something I am getting in console.

Comment: It's a problem relative to the scope. You need to add the bind or the arrow function.

Comment: i guess there is some scope problem. can you share more code to understand the issue. Also, Initialise you state in constructor and try to do your api calls in componentDidMount.

Comment: @SDushan & others, BTW, Is the url I am giving in axios.get(url) correct? When I do console.log(res.data) it shows the code of a whole html page and not any data in json format.

Comment: @Ravi Singh, Hi, I have edited my question to share more code to understand the issue. Thanks

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar you can't access state as above in functional component, use React hooks or use class component as below example.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can handle `axios` in below approaches

**Promise approach**

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://api.myslambook.in/swagger/#/users/', {
        auth: {
            username: 'xxxx',
            password: 'xxxxx'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        this.setState({
            serverData: res.data.serverData
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**Async/await approach**

```
async componentDidMount(){
    try {
        let response = await axios.get('http://api.myslambook.in/swagger/#/users/', {
            auth: {
                username: 'xxxx',
                password: 'xxxxx'
            }
        })
        this.setState({
            serverData: response.data.serverData
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

For more information check below example code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {
    state = { 
        isLoading: true
    }

  componentDidMount(){
    return axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: res.data.movies,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: BTW, Is the url I am giving in axios.get(url) correct? When I do console.log(res.data) it shows the code of a whole html page and not any data in json format.

Comment: try to add ```headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}``` as an axios headers